# facebook connect SDK sample: how to retrieve location and birthday?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the offcial sample from facebook: it works fine, except I cannot retrieve the birthday and location.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,gender,location,email,birthday',  {fields: 'name, email,gender,first_name,last_name,location,birthday' }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button show-faces="false" scope="public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location" size="medium" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Connect with facebook</fb:login-button>


<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine but no borthday nor location in response.

I spent a lot of time and it looks that nowdays to retrieve these informations I **need to nowdays to REVIEW the application before accessing these data**
[image: facebook rights]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

Is this correct: do I need to submit the application for review or is it something wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true, and it's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

But, if you're using the an admin/tester/developer of the said app, you are able to give and test these permission with your app. Only if third parties will need to access the app, you'll need to pass Login Review.